# database name in mysql seems valid but it is showing an error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a database with a '-' in between two words and it should work perfectly fine but it isn't. here is the log file:

```
mysql> create database test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+-----------------------+
| Database              |
+-----------------------+
| information_schema    |
| mifos                 |
| mifosplatform_tenants |
| mifostenant           |
| mifostenant_default   |
| mysql                 |
| performance_schema    |
| sakila                |
| test                  |
| test1                 |
| testing               |
| world                 |
+-----------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database test1-mohit;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-mohi
t' at line 1
```

Comment: can not use of hyphen in database name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `_(underscore)`

```
create database test1_mohit;
```

or try this

```
  create database `test1_mohit`;
```

These both will work

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these character for naming database `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]`

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html